# How do I record a single keypress in Scheme?

Tags: input, io, scheme

I can't find out how to record a single keypress, like a single character or an arrow, or modifier keys like shift.

The closest thing is `read-char` but that waits for you to press enter before it sends the input. I want to just register the keypress and immediatly pass it through.

In case this is implementation-specific, I'm using Chez-Scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned keypresses are system specific, but on a linux or BSD system, which will almost certainly have stty installed, this will do what you want with chez scheme:

```
(system "stty --file=/dev/tty cbreak -echo")
(let ([keyboard (open-input-file "/dev/tty")])
  (format #t "The key press was ~A~%" (read-char keyboard)))
(system "stty --file=/dev/tty -cbreak echo")
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Anything to do with keypresses will be implementation specific, as it is not addressed in the Scheme standard. In Chez Scheme, there is no direct support for keypresses, as far as I know. However, if you install SWL (Scheme Widget Library) that is provided along with Chez Scheme, there is a command to read keypresses. I've never used it and don't know anything about it.

Comment: Hmm too bad. I guess I'll have to take a look at SWL then. Thanks

Comment: It seems R6RS has a possibility to read and write files with unbuffered ports but no feature to turn on/off buffering on already opened ports. Perhaps R7RS-large will have it.

Comment: @Silvester: Port buffering isn't the issue, and making it unbuffered won't help.  Its the terminal's own line buffering which is the problem.